WSO2 Data Services call hold connection
I use Oracle DB and have a query in WSO2:
<query id="logThirdPartyResponseProc" useConfig="DBConfig">
    <sql>CALL LOG3NRPARTYRES(:P_APINAME, :P_SVCSOURCE, :P_APPREQID,
      :P_GLOBALID, :P_BODY, :P_ERR_CODE)</sql>
    <param type="IN" name="P_APINAME" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="true" defaultValue="#{NULL}" />
    <param type="IN" name="P_SVCSOURCE" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="true" defaultValue="#{NULL}" />
    <param type="IN" name="P_APPREQID" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="true" defaultValue="#{NULL}" />
    <param type="IN" name="P_GLOBALID" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="true" defaultValue="#{NULL}" />
    <param type="IN" name="P_BODY" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="CLOB" optional="true" defaultValue="#{NULL}" />
    <param type="OUT" name="P_ERR_CODE" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" optional="false" />
    <result element="result" rowName="results">
      <element name="errorCode" column="P_ERR_CODE" xsdType="string" requiredRoles="" />
    </result>
  </query>

And I call the operation uses that query in a Template Mediator:
<template name="TPLogThirdPartyRequest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter defaultValue="" isMandatory="false" name="apiName"/>
    <parameter defaultValue="" isMandatory="false" name="svcSource"/>
    <sequence>
        <dataServiceCall serviceName="DBTest">
            <operations type="single">
                <operation name="logThirdPartyRequestOpration">
                    <param evaluator="xml" expression="$func:apiName" name="pApiName"/>
                    <param evaluator="xml" expression="$func:svcSource" name="pSvcSource"/>
                    <param evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('pAppReqId')" name="pAppReqId"/>
                    <param evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('pGlobalId')" name="pGlobalId"/>
                    <param evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('pThirPartyRequestBody')" name="pBody"/>
                </operation>
            </operations>
            <source type="inline"/>
            <target name="logThirdPartyRequestErrorCode" type="property"/>
        </dataServiceCall>
        <log level="full"/>
    </sequence>
</template>

When I call above template in my sequence, the procedure executes successfully, but checking in toad I see the connection which executes the procedure still opening. That's because after a time I faced connection pool leak.
I tried with Abadon properties but the issue persists:
pool_options.removeAbandoned = true
pool_options.removeAbandonedTimeout  = 60 # wait in seconds
pool_options.logAbandoned = true    

Which the best solution to solve this issue?

Do you see the same issue when you access the service over the network?

@ycr Yeb, local and services built in docker swarm has same issue
